# How do I enter angle brackets in bibtex?

Tags: latex, bibtex

I want to put a title field in a bibtex citation that includes angle brackets:

```
@article{
  title= { <foo> }
}
```

but when it compiles I get upside down '!' and '?' instead. How to escape the angle bracket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main TeX font doesn't provide angle brackets—you have to use math symbols.  Try

```
title = { $\langle$Foo$\rangle$ }
```

and be prepared for potential difficulties with alphabetization.

Comment: You're assuming he wants that kind of angle brackets.  $<$Foo$>$, or  {\tt <}Foo{\tt >} are other possibilities that might be more what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had a great deal of trouble with angle brackets in my doi fields until I switched to using the `biblatex` package. With the `natbib=true` option set, this was nearly a drop-in replacement for `natbib`. The angle brackets problem solved itself without further work on my part and my doi's became clickable. I don't know if it would work for your title brackets, but I'd suggest it as worth looking into.